# if logic based on DNS name resolution results in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, dns, powercli

I am writing a script in PowerShell that performs some actions based on user input. The user input is supposed to be the name of an ESX host. I want to perform a DNS check against their input to validate if it is usable or not.

Looking at my code below, I am wondering what the syntax would be to make the if statement succeed based on a positive DNS return and hit the else in the event that the input doesn't resolve in the DNS check.

Just as a note, i stripped out all the meat to simplify this. I am only interested in controlling the IF logic based on the results of a DNS resolution check. The code as below, never fails because i never get a null response from the dns check.

```
$esx = Read-Host -Prompt "enter stuff here"
$hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::Resolve($esx).HostName

if ($hostname -ne $null){    
Write-Host "Connected to:"$esx
}
else {
Write-Host "oops"
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: It cannot fail. DNS resolution doesn't return a null on failure.

Comment: I disagree. It not only returns null for a machine that does not exist, it trhows an error. `$foo = [System.Net.DNS]::Resolve('poopyface').HostName; $foo -eq $null` True

Comment: strange, in testing, I can type anything I can think of but it never jumps to oops. It always tries the success.

Comment: It fails correctly on my machine. Which version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: Version          : 5.0.10586.117

Comment: perhaps the issue isnt in the code, maybe its something with our dns environment. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Yep, turns out there is a security policy in place preventing me from using pure dns. Thanks for the help guys, great information.